# Why do I get syntax error when i am running parse-server app on my local server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have Parse server application cloned on my local server. I have installed nodejs, mongodb and other packages which is required for parse server. I used this application from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/. whenever I run parse server on my local server i am getting the syntax error. Below is the screen shot of error:[image]

Comment: You *"used the application"* how exactly? How did you install this on your local machine? The error is telling you that the library code cannot be found.

Comment: These are steps which i have used to install this on my local machine:

npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
mongodb-runner start
parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY

Answer (score 0):

`Parse Server` that you downloaded is just the server framework. If you start it you cannot use it because **it is not linked to a http web server.** Most preferred web server for parse is `express`.

If you are a beginner then it would be better if you **start with the `parse-server-example`.** It provides a minimal working parse server that you can use. You can find more details here:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have done it with parse-server-example and it works fine. I am doing the same process with parse-sever but it throws error.

Comment: read the first portion of my answer? Have you mounted parse-server on as an express app??

Comment: I have installed express but don't know how to mount parse-server as an express. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Instead of mounting it yourself, the best option is to edit the parse-server-example and implement your code in it.